# How to Efficiently Map Nested JSON to Custom Lua Data Structures in a REST API Client?

Tags: json, lua, cjson

I'm working on a REST API client in Lua that consumes data from a third-party service. The service returns deeply nested JSON objects, and I need to map these to more simplified Lua tables for easier manipulation and data analysis. I've explored using libraries like `cjson` for basic deserialization, but I'm struggling with mapping the nested JSON to my custom data structures efficiently.

Here's a simplified example of the JSON object returned by the API:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "attributes": {
      "name": "John",
      "details": {
        "age": 30,
        "address": {
          "street": "123 Main St",
          "city": "Anytown"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here's what I would like to map this to in Lua:

```lua
Person = {
  id = 1,
  name = "John",
  age = 30,
  street_address = "123 Main St",
  city = "Anytown"
}
```

Is there a best practice for this type of mapping? Are there any Lua libraries that can assist with this, or should I be writing custom mapping functions? I'm concerned about both code maintainability and performance.

Thank you in advance for any insights or recommendations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "traversing JSON" functionality is useful here.

```
local json = require"json"
local s = [[
{
   "data": {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
         "name": "John",
         "details": {
            "age": 30,
            "address": {
               "street": "123 Main St",
               "city": "Anytown"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
]]
local Person = {}

json.traverse(s,
   function (path, json_type, value, pos, pos_last)
      local path_str = table.concat(path, "/")
      print("DEBUG:", path_str, json_type, value, pos, pos_last)
      if json_type == "number" or json_type == "string" then
         Person[path[#path]] = value
      end
   end
)

print"RESULT"
for k,v in pairs(Person) do
   print(k, v)
end
```

Output:

```
DEBUG:                                          object  nil          1    nil
DEBUG:  data                                    object  nil          14   nil
DEBUG:  data/id                                 number  1            28   28
DEBUG:  data/attributes                         object  nil          51   nil
DEBUG:  data/attributes/name                    string  John         70   75
DEBUG:  data/attributes/details                 object  nil          98   nil
DEBUG:  data/attributes/details/age             number  30           119  120
DEBUG:  data/attributes/details/address         object  nil          146  nil
DEBUG:  data/attributes/details/address/street  string  123 Main St  173  185
DEBUG:  data/attributes/details/address/city    string  Anytown      211  219
RESULT
name    John
street  123 Main St
city    Anytown
age     30
id      1
```

The library is [here](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/json4lua)